Nginx alias for single php file returns 404 (other files are ok)
I'm trying to serve a single php file with Nginx 1.22.1. I'm using this kind of approach:
# PHP file alias:
location /netbootassets/fragment.php {
  alias /opt/easy_multi_pxe/scripts/fragment.php;
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
}

However, when I access the file I get 404 Not Found.
The same mechanism for regular files works perfectly:
# Regular file alias:
location /netbootassets/foo.txt {
  alias /tmp/foo.txt;
}

I have seen some answers about aliasing but no answers seem to concern a single php file.

I got it to work. There was missing = . This stanza works:
# PHP file alias:
location = /netbootassets/fragment.php {
  alias /opt/easy_multi_pxe/scripts/fragment.php;
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
}

